# ThreeJS : Raycasts is off on some computers

Tags: three.js, raycasting, orthographic

I've been doing a ThreeJS project and using raycasting to interesect with objects within the canvas.
I have 4 computers to test it on, all updated with the latest repo.

On one of the computers the raycasting is off from where the mouse are... and I have no idea what is causing it to behave differently from the others.

Any ideas?

The code:

```
// Performs a Raycast for Ortho camera type
PerformOrthographicRaycast: function (event, canvas, renderer, camera, objects) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    var dir = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    vector.x = ((event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left) / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
    vector.y = -((event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top) / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;;
    vector.z = -1; // z = - 1 important!

    vector.unproject(camera);

    dir.set(0, 0, -1).transformDirection(camera.matrixWorld);

    this._Raycaster.set(vector, dir);
    var intersects = this._Raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);

    if (intersects.length) {
        return intersects;
    }
    else
        return null;
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with Windows "enlarge" or "scale" users can set in their theme settings.

In the renderer you can find the pixelratio which is modified when the scaling has been changed. The following solution works for me:

```
vector.x = renderer.devicePixelRatio * ((event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left) / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
vector.y = renderer.devicePixelRatio * -((event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top) / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;;
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes_ortho). Look at messages in the console.

```
<script src="js/controls/EventsControls.js"></script>

EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
EventsControls.draggable = false;

EventsControls.mouseOver = function () {
    this.container.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    this.mouseOvered.currentHex = this.mouseOvered.material.emissive.getHex();
    this.mouseOvered.material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 );

    console.log( 'the key at number ' + this.mouseOveredItem + ' is select' );                          
}   

//

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh ); 

EventsControls.attach( mesh );

//

function render() {
       EventsControls.update();
       controls.update();
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```